# Small device with Bluetooth low energy (BLE)

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I need an small device with bluetooth that has to do the following:

1. Have an accelerometer attached and read his data.
2. After x seconds, send the accelerometer data to the paired device over bluetooth.

The device has to be small and portable. I've found the following ones, but I don't know if they suit well or not: [Micro:bit BBC](http://microbit.org/guide/), [Lilypad Simblee](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13633).

What other alternatives I have?

Comment: How is the accelerometer attached? The Beetle, BLE Nano, and Pi Zero come to mind, but they may not have the I/O you want.

Comment: I2c most probably. Here tou have an example: https://learn.adafruit.com/flora-accelerometer/wiring-with-conductive-thread

Comment: [Related - your previous question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/device-with-ble-wi-fi-accelerometers-and-battery)

Answer (score 1):

## The [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/#buy-now-modal)

It's $10, comes with Bluetooth LE and Wi-Fi onboard, and [can be *very* easily set for use with an I2C sensor.](https://www.maxbotix.com/Setup-Raspberry-Pi-Zero-for-i2c-Sensor-151) [Under full load it draws a only 1.2W](http://raspi.tv/2017/how-much-power-does-pi-zero-w-use), but has enough horses to keep pace. Best of all, it has a massive community backing it, [including a StackExchange community!](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

The biggest drawback comes in the niche I/O choices compared to a larger board–unless you're a camera or tech geek, chances are you don't have a mini HDMI port, and you'll need to provide your own micro SD card. That said, it has a bounty compared to other similar boards like the Beetle LE or BLE Nano, and you'll probably find it easier to work with as a result.

Comment: It would be possible to use it as a portable project with his own baterry and lasts for weeks?

Comment: @Lechucico Depends on the power draw of the accelerometer, but the board itself on a fairly generous 20000 mAh battery bank should do just about a week.

Comment: Do you know more devices for portable solutions?

Comment: Besides the other two I listed, it seems to pretty much be breakout boards. There's fatter boards for sure, but that seems in conflict with your goals.